# Get data from DB based on selected values. Vue.js + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a table with bank deposits wich contains the next rows:

```
        currency | period | percents.
```

On frontend i have 2 select fields and 1 input:

```
            <select name="currency" class="form-control" v-model="currency">
                <option>USD</option>
                <option>EUR</option>
            </select>

            <select name="period" class="form-control" v-model="period">
                <option>6</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>24</option>
            </select>

        <input class="form-control" type="text"  value="@{{ percents }}" v-model="percents">
```

So I need to get a percents value into input field depending on these selected options.
For example user selects USD and 12 monts, and automatically appears percentages for selected options. 
If somebody will provide just a simple example would be very happy.

Comment: you have to send the ajax request to get the data since it will change dynamically based on the user selected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [computed](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) properties and ajax call. Everytime user change the option, the percent in text box will re-evaluate. Here the example using VueJS and [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource).

```js
new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    currency: '',
    period: '',
  },

  computed: {
    percents() {

      var url = "/get_percent/" + this.currency + '/' + this.period;

      this.$http.get(url, function(response){
        return response.percents;
      });

      return this.currency + ' - ' + this.period;
    }
  }

});
```

Here the snippet http://jsbin.com/qorovo/edit?html,js,output

From the Laravel side, you could return simple JSON

```php
Route::get('/get_percent/{currency}/{period}', function($currency, $period) 
{
    return App\Deposit::where('currency', $currency)
                      ->where('period', $period)
                      ->first();
});
```

Comment: I did everything as you described and it works. The only 1 problem I have is - the "percentages" is not appears in the percentage input field, when I use return response.percents. PHP returs the correct value, but console lo shows undefined.

Comment: Ok. It was some mistakes from my side now it works fine. Big Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can not give you exact code but I can help you 
**Step 1**
Detect when the user select options using `jQuery or JavaScript`
**Step 2**
then send an ajax request to controller like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/home",
            type: 'post or get',
            data: data to send to server,
            success: function(){
                console.log("success");
            },
        error: function(){
            $(".necessary-fields").show();

        }
        });
```

**Step 3** 
Set up the route
Route::post('home', 'MyController@getData')

**Step 4**
in your controller

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public function getData(){
        //fetch data from db
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this variant.